# SQL 2012 - substituir (nolock) por with(nolock)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

Preciso de ajuda para resolver um problema de incompatibilidade.
A empresa que trabalho está efetuando a migração de um Banco SQL Server 2008 para 2012, porem identificamos alguns problemas.

O principal deles é a declaração do `(NOLOCK)` sem o `WITH` nas VIEWs, FUNCs e PROCs, quando utilizando linked server, apresenta erro e devemos incluir o `WITH`.

Os objetos criados, muitas vezes, possuem a declaração do SELECT onde é mencionado um "alias" para a tabela em questão.
Ex: `Select * from customer as c`
ou  `Select * from customer c`

Nesses casos para piorar meu problema, o `(NOLOCK)` foi incluído entre a tabela e o alias.
ex:

```
Select * form customer `(NOLOCK)` as c
```

Em uma mudança em massa, como REPLACE (NOLOCK) por WITH(NOLOCK), ficará dessa forma:

```
Select * from customer `WITH(NOLOCK)` as c
```

Apresentando erro na execução/compilação.

Mas como fazer isso de uma forma "rápida" quando temos mais de 900 objetos entre os citados acima?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta de acordo com a sua atualização.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Atenção: Faça um backup antes da sua base de dados**. O ideal é executar isso numa base de teste.

Pela interface gráfica do  SQL Management Studio:

- Clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima do banco de dados que você deseja;
- Selecionar a opção **Gerar Scripts**.
- Avançar e selecionar para quais tipos de objeto você deseja gerar o script.
- Na tela aonde aparece como você quer exportar, clique no botão Avançado e marque a opção **Script DROP e CREATE** para a opção de mesmo nome.
- Realizar a exportação;
- Feito isso, abra o arquivo gerado e com um editor como Notepad++ substitua (NOLOCK) por WITH (NOLOCK)
- Carregue esse arquivo no SQL Management Studio e execute-o.

Como eu disse, faça testes antes de rodar em produção. Se você não puder fazer numa base de teste, então exporte apenas duas stored procedures e veja se funciona.

**Atualização**

A opção **Script DROP e CREATE** garante que será gerado um DROP para cada objeto, pois só dando DROP e criando novamente você conseguirá realizar essa operação. Você poderia usar o ALTER, porém não existe essa opção no gerador de script (pelo menos na minha versão).

Uma outra coisa que você precisa verificar é se o gerador de script escreverá no arquivo respeitando as dependências entre os objetos. Isso é importante, pois você não pode dropar uma function que está sendo utilizada numa Stored Procedure. Assim, é preciso antes dropar a SP, para depois dropar a Function.

### Atualização 2 (Conforme atualização da pergunta):

**Expressão regular no Notepad++ versão 6.4.5**

No Notepad++ existe a opção de encontrar e subsituir um texto por expressão regular. Para isso, aperte CTRL-F e utilize a opção Regular Expression:

**1o Passo**

Procure por isso:

```
\(NOLOCK\)
```

Substitua por isso:

```
\1WITH \(NOLOCK\)
```

**2o Passo**

Procure por isso:

```
(WITH\s+\(NOLOCK\))\s+(AS\s+[A-Z]+)
```

Substitua por isso:

```
\2 \1
```

**Teste**:

No 1o passo, isso:

```
Select * from QUOTE (NOLOCK) AS TB
```

É transformado nisso:

```
Select * from QUOTE WITH (NOLOCK) AS TB
```

Que no 2o passo é transformado nisso:

```
Select * from QUOTE AS TB WITH (NOLOCK)
```

### **Explicação sobre a Expressão Regular**:

```
(WITH\s+\(NOLOCK\))\s+(AS\s+[A-Z]+)
```

Primeiro vamos quebrá-la em três pedaços:

```
(WITH\s+\(NOLOCK\))
\s+
(AS\s+[A-Z]+)
```

Note que o 1o e 3o pedaços estão delimitados por paranteses. O 1o pedaço é chamado de \1 e o 3o pedaço é chamado de \2. Grave isso.

**1o pedaço:**

```
WITH
\s+
\(NOLOCK\)
```

Este pedaço está procurando pela string WITH em qualquer lugar da linha. Depois que enontrar, são consumidos quantos espaços em brancos existirem (\s+) até encontar a string (NOLOCK). As barras invertidas são necessárias para escapar o caracter paranteses, já que o mesmo é um caracter reservado.

**2o pedaço:**

O 2o pedaço (\s+) é apenas uma forma de percorremos todos os espaços existentes entre (NOLOCK) e a palavra AS.

**3o pedaço:**

```
AS
\s+
[A-Z]+
```

O 3o pedaço encontra a palavra AS que deve vir necessariamente após 1 ou vários espaços em branco (já que vem depois do 2o pedaço).

Feito isso, são percorridos um ou mais espaços em brancos até se encontre uma palavra que tenha uma ou mais caracteres (de A-Z). Esse é nome da tabela que vem depois do AS.

**Substituição**

Como explicado acima, a expressão regular está dividida em dois grupos (o 1o e 3o pedaços). Portanto, a substituição é simplesmente reescrever o 3o pedaço + um espaço em branco + 1o pedaço, assim:

```
\2 \1
```

Comment: Cantoni, o problema é um pouco mais complexo, sendo somente a inclusão do WITH não suficiente pelo seguinte motivo.

Muitos dos Objetos estão declarados da seguinte forma:
Ex: Select * from TABELA (NOLOCK) as TB 
ou
Select * from TABELA (NOLOCK) TB

caso eu inclua o WITH apresentará erro na compilação/execução.
Select * from TABELA WITH(NOLOKC) as TB

Comment: Entendi. Inclua isso na pergunta. De qualquer maneira, você não tem outra opção a não ser realmente recompilar tudo. Talvez você precise de usar replace com expressão regular ou, em último caso, processar o arquivo gerado pelo script. Na verdade, o essencial da resposta é a maneira de exportar todos os objetos. Tendo tudo isso em um arquivo texto é possível fazer as alterações em massa.

Comment: Cantoni, sabe explicar o que significa os caracteres?
Ex: \2 - \1 - \s - *[A-Z] - etc?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com a sua dúvida. Não tem como fazer nada que vá funcionar na primeira execução. Eu não vi o seu arquivo com o dump. Você certamente terá que modificar essa solução em algum ponto. . O que fiz aqui foi tentar te dar algumas ferramentas para que você consiga seguir e resolver.

Comment: Cantoni, não sei como agradecer, fantástico sua sugestão e mais ainda a explicação, muitíssimo obrigado!!!!

Comment: A melhor maneira de agradecer aqui é aceitando a resposta que você considera a melhor e votando nas demais que você também tenha gostado. Note que você também pode votar na questão que você aceitar como correta. Agora o mais importante é que você pode votar em qualquer pergunta e resposta do site (desde que não sejam as suas). Votos geram credibilidade nas perguntas e resposta, por isso são tão necessário dentro da filosofia do SE. Espero que você tenha sucesso em seu desafio. Bom Trabalho!